# error.message.indexOf is not a function truffle ganache

Tags: truffle, blockchain, ganache, truffle-contract, mocha

**for truffle developers**

```
var Election = artifacts.require('./Election.sol');

contract("Election",function(accounts){
var electionInstance;

it("throws an exception for double voting",function(){
    return Election.deployed().then(function(instance){
        electionInstance = instance;
        candidateId = 2;
        electionInstance.vote(candidateId , { from:accounts[4] });
        return electionInstance.candidates(candidateId);
    }).then(function(candidate){
        var voteCount = candidate[2];
        assert.equal(voteCount,1 ,"accepts first vote");
        return electionInstance.vote(candidateId,{from : accounts[1] });
    }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error){
          //error at this line
        assert(error.message.indexOf('revert')>=0,'error message must constain revert'); 
        return electionInstance.candidates(1);
    })
});

});
```

return the error as

> 1. Contract: Election
>    throws an exception for double voting:
>    TypeError: error.message.indexOf is not a function

Comment: Use await instead of .then(...)

Comment: And use this library to catch reverts npm i @openzeppelin/test-helpers